# MPMoviePlayerController stalling frequently

Tags: ios, video, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play remote mp4 files which are not quite big, about 20 - 30 MB each. This is how the player is set up:

```
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
player.shouldAutoplay  = YES;
```

The problem is that the player stops frequently with the following console output:

```
Took background task assertion ... for playback stall   // stops
Ending background task assertion ... for playback stall // resumes
```

I possibly could have taken this behavior as granted, but on the other hand when I try to play the video in other streaming player (e.g. GoodPlayer) - it plays nicely and never stops. So the problem is in my approach itself, not in the Internet connection.

Are there any ways to make MPMoviePlayerController to load seamlessly, or do I have to change components used in my app? If yes, which ones would you recommend?

Comment: I have this problem as well, so... will let you know

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Morkrom - did you figure this one out?

Comment: Internet speed. You loose stream guys.

Comment: @NikGreen Any luck for this. We are facing huge problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign (declare) MPMoviePlayerController as @property in your .h file, rather than a local variable.